# Capturing a `thread_local` in a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdthread, thread-local-storage

Capturing a thread_local in a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

struct Person
{
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    thread_local Person user{"mike"};
    Person& referenceToUser = user;

    // Works fine - Prints "Hello mike"
    std::thread([&]() {std::cout << "Hello " << referenceToUser.name << std::endl;}).join();

    // Doesn't work - Prints "Hello"
    std::thread([&]() {std::cout << "Hello " << user.name << std::endl;}).join();

    // Works fine - Prints "Hello mike"
    std::thread([&user=user]() {std::cout << "Hello " << user.name << std::endl;}).join();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zeocG5ohb

It seems like if I use the original name of a `thread_local` then its value on the thread which executes the lambda is the `thread_local` version of the thread which is running the lambda. But as soon as I take a reference or pointer to the thread local it turns into (a pointer to) the *originating* threads instance.

What are the rules here. Can I rely on this analysis?

Comment: Please explain what "Works fine" and "Doesn't work" mean so people don't have to click through and figure out what you could mean.

Comment: From my reading of cppreference, this just isn't allowed: *A lambda expression can use a variable without capturing it if the variable

is a non-local variable or has static or thread local storage duration (in which case the variable cannot be captured), or*  source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike I think it's ok as in example 2 I'm not capturing anything at all (you can remove the `&` in the `[&]`. Example 1 and 3 I'm capturing something which _isn't_ the `thread_local`. Example 2 still has an issue as discussed in the accepted answer though.

Comment: @MikeVine What I was getting at is that 2 doesn't capture `user` even though you specified `&`.  Instead you have a new thread local variable in your lambda that has never been initialized

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike: "new thread local variable in your lambda".  Well not exactly.  A thread local variable with a new instance in the `std::thread`, which the lambda finds when it runs inside the `std::thread`.  But it isn't "in the lambda", as that same exact lambda could be executed on the main thread and find the old thread local instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Similar to local `static` objects, local `thread_local` (implicitly `static thread_local`) objects are initialized when control passes through their declaration for the first time.

The thread you are creating never executes `main`, only the main thread does, so you're accessing `user` before its lifetime has begun on the extra thread.

#### Your three cases explained

```cpp
std::thread([&]() {std::cout << "Hello " << referenceToUser.name << std::endl;}).join();
```

We are capturing `referenceToUser` which refers to the `user` on the main thread. This is okay.

```cpp
std::thread([&]() {std::cout << "Hello " << user.name << std::endl;}).join();
```

We are accessing `user` on the extra thread before its lifetime has begun. This is undefined behavior.

```cpp
std::thread([&user=user]() {std::cout << "Hello " << user.name << std::endl;}).join();
```

Once again, we are referencing the `user` from the main thread here, which is same as the first case.

#### Possible fix

If you declare `user` outside of `main`, then `user` will be initialized when your thread starts, not when `main` runs:

```cpp
thread_local Person user{"mike"};

int main() {
    // ...
```

Alternatively, declare `user` inside of your lambda expression.

---

*Note: It's not necessary to capture `thread_local` objects. The second example could be `[] { ... }`.*

Comment: I guess this is a choice the designers of C++ made - whether to (for want of a better phrase) "capture thread_locals by name instead of by address". I guess statics & globals & function-names, etc are all captured by name but for those it really doesn't matter as they don't change across threads. For thread_locals it does matter the choice and it seems like they're treated as statics instead of locals.

Comment: I guess not "capturing by name" effectively means they don't need to be stored at all so this lambda in example 2 is stateless. I think I get it now. Not that I think this is the right choice, but I guess the user can use the method I use in example 1 or 3 to change this to the other option so its a better choice, even if slightly confusing at first look.

Comment: @MikeVine if you used the method from example 1 or 3, then there would be no point to using `thread_local`, since all threads are using the same object. Also, I think this behavior for `static thread_local` is a massive footgun in C++, and very bad design. You don't even get a warning and I couldn't get any sanitizer to catch this mistake.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily not useful - I can think of times where I want to pass in the `thread_local` by "address" and let _other_ threads use it. Imagine a logger which wrote to the log file on another thread and I wanted that logger to reference _this threads_ instance of a thread_local. That could (and would) work via example 1 or 3. It would be niche tho.

Comment: Why not just capture the tread_id by value? Is there even a guarantee that the tread that started the logging still "exists" by the time the logging is processed on the background thread. I've done a lot of multithreading programming (about 25 years) and I only really needed thread_local only once or twice (so it is not the first solution I look for).

Comment: Here is attempt to force manifestation of UB: https://godbolt.org/z/zvMacxWca

Comment: I think there's an aspect this is ignoring -- see https://godbolt.org/z/eTofxeYz6.  There's no UB here, but you still get the same pattern of different behaviour.  The behaviour is correct and expected in this case, I think; 1 & 3 are capturing the value from the main thread while 2 is independently accessing the value from the new thread.

Comment: @Miral yes, this behavior is correct and expected. If you look at my answer, specifically the "Your three cases explained" section, you will confirm that the output is different because the main thread's `user` object is used.

Answer (score 1):

`[&]` is a very dangerous thing to do when your lambda executes outside of the immediate context.  It is very useful there -- otherwise, it is a bad plan.

In this case, you are being bitten by the fact that `[&]` does *not* capture global, local static or thread local variables.  So using `[]` in this case would behave the same.

```
thread_local Person user{"mike"};
Person& referenceToUser = user;

std::thread([&]() {std::cout << "Hello " << referenceToUser.name << std::endl;}).join();
```

this captures `referenceToUser` by reference.  `referenceToUser` in turn refers to the `thread_local` variable in the main thread.

```
std::thread([&]() {std::cout << "Hello " << user.name << std::endl;}).join();
```

this is identical to

```
std::thread([]() {std::cout << "Hello " << user.name << std::endl;}).join();
```

the use of `[&]` here makes you believe it is capturing `user` by reference.  So the `thread_local` variable `main::user` is being used.  As the thread never passed the initialization line of that variable, you have just done UB.

```
std::thread([&user=user]() {std::cout << "Hello " << user.name << std::endl;}).join();
```

here you explicitly create a new reference variable `user` at lambda creation.

The basic rule is **never use `[&]` when creating a lambda to pass to a `std::thread`.

This is appropriate use of `[&]`:

```
foreach_chicken( [&](chicken& c){ /* process chicken */ } );
```

the lambda is expected to exist within the current scope, and is going to be executed locally.  `[&]` is safe.

```
auto pop = [&]()->std::optional<int>{
  if (queue.empty()) return std::nullopt;
   auto x = std::move(queue.front());
   queue.pop_front();
   return x;
 };
 while (auto x = pop()) {
 }
```

this is another example of a valid use of `[&]`, as this `pop` operation is being refactored into a helper and maybe run more than once in the local function.

But if the lambda is not being run locally or could live beyond the current scope, `[&]` is a toxic option that leads to surprises and bugs in pretty much every case I've seen it used.